# Primefaces p:commandButton with action not called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, actionlistener

I've got some some troubles with Primefaces 3.2 and JSF 2.1.

My Code like this:

```
<p:toolbar id="jeditortoolbar" styleClass="jeditortoolbar">
      <p:toolbarGroup align="left" height="25" style="height:25px">
        <p:commandButton type="button" title="#{msg.beenden}"/>
        <p:commandButton type="button" title="#{msg.neu}"/>
      </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```

When I take a look at Primefaces Showcase my p:commandButton need

```
actionListener="#{myBean.myActionMethod}"
```

and my Bean need a Method like

```
public void myActionMethod(){}
```

I have a `h:form` around my `p:toolbar` tag!

My Bean is ViewScoped.

My Workaround is 
In `*.xhtml` File

```
<p:commandButton type="button" title="#{msg.neu}" onclick="addNewEmptyFile()"/>
<p:remoteCommand name="addNewEmptyFile" update=":codeTabForm">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{myBean.myEvent}"/>
</p:remoteCommand>
```

In MyBean.java

```
private String myEvent;

public void setMyEvent(String value){ myActionMethod();}
```

This works for me but I think this is very dirty code.

Can everyone help me?

Comment: Where is the problem? What happens if you try it like in the showcase?

Comment: When i add the ActionListener Methode the Event is not Called.

Comment: Did you try removing `type="button"` from your command buttons?

Comment: thanks that it the stupid remove type="button" make my day. thanks alot

Comment: No, "everyone" cannot help you. Some can though. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

**Bean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    public String testButtonAction() {
        System.out.println("testButtonAction invoked");
        return "anotherPage.xhtml";
    }

    public void testButtonActionListener(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("testButtonActionListener invoked");
    }

}
```

page.xhtml

```
<p:toolbar>
  <p:toolbarGroup>
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.testButtonAction}"/>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.testButtonActionListener}"/>
  </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```

Comment: I really wish some day the IDE could warn the developer about this instead of simply ignoring the method signature mismatch ;-)

Comment: For future reference: In my case I copied the attribute type=button from some example and wondered why this code works and my button had not.

Comment: removing type="button" fixed my issue

Comment: removing type="submit" fixed the issue for me