# p:commandButton ajax not called inside p:dataList - even when its wrapped in p:column

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I am having the same problems as this post: [p:commandButton ajax not called inside p:dataList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761958/pcommandbutton-ajax-not-called-inside-pdatalist)

where a p:commandButton's action / actionListener is not being called when placed in a p:dataList.

I followed the advice and wrapped the p:commandButton in a p:column, and also just for testing followed the code here: [Primefaces p:commandButton with action not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856843/primefaces-pcommandbutton-with-action-not-called?rq=1)

..to test both action and actionListener attempts at sending an ajax call to my backing bean.

Both are called when placed outside the p:dataList .. just never when inside it.

Here's my backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FullScreenDashboardBean implements Serializable {
...
   public String testButtonAction() {
        log.info("testButtonAction invoked");
        return "";
    }

    public void testButtonActionListener(ActionEvent event) {
        log.info("testButtonActionListener invoked");
    }
...
}
```

/////////////////

// xhtml code:
...

```
<div class="left_content">
  <h:form id="leftContentForm">  

   <p:dataList value="#{clientTargetURLsBean.clientAndTUrlList}" var ="selectedClients" id="selectedClientListTest"  paginator="false" type="none">  
    <p:column>          
     <p:commandButton action="#{fullScreenDashboardBean.testButtonAction}"/>
     <p:commandButton actionListener="#{fullScreenDashboardBean.testButtonActionListener}"/>
    </p:column> 
   </p:dataList>
...

 </h:form>
</div>
```

They both fire backing bean's listeners when outside the datalist, but not when placed inside....

Any ideas - massively appreciated...

Thank you stackoverflow-ers!

Comment: I could not replicate the error.. The above example work fine for me... Are you sure that you don't have nested forms or anything like that?

Comment: Thanks for testing... No nested forms, just checked...  Strangely, it works locally, but not when pushed up to GAE