# Command Button wont work primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I have xhtml page which has data grid inside that data grid i want to call a method by using a button or link button I  coded as following to do that

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>        
</h:head>    
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <p:graphicImage value="images/common/banner1.png" 
                            style="width: 100%;min-width: 1350px"/>                
            <h:form id="menu_bar_form">  
                <p:menubar style="font-size: 14px;min-width: 1340px;" >  
                    <p:menuitem style="width: 50px" disabled="true"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="HOME" url="home.xhtml"/>
                    <p:menuitem style="width: 100px" disabled="true"/>                       
                    <p:submenu label="PHONES">
                        <p:menuitem value="Apple" outcome="phones">
                            <f:param name="brand" value="Apple"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem value="Motorola" outcome="phones">
                            <f:param name="brand" value="Motorola"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem value="Nokia" outcome="phones">
                            <f:param name="brand" value="Nokia"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem value="Samsung" outcome="phones">
                            <f:param name="brand" value="Samsung"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:menuitem style="width: 100px" disabled="true"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="COMPARE"/>
                    <p:menuitem style="width: 100px" disabled="true"/>
                    <p:submenu label="ACCESSORIES">  
                       //ADD CONTENT 
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:menuitem style="width: 100px" disabled="true"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="CONTACT"/>
                    <f:facet name="options">  
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="font-size: 12px">
                            <p:autoComplete id="search_textBox" value="#{homeBean.searchItem}"   
                                            completeMethod="#{homeBean.search}"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </f:facet> 
                </p:menubar>
            </h:form>
            <h:form id="page_content">
                <table cellspacing="2" style="font-size: 14px;
                       width: 100%;min-width: 1350px">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th style="width: 1000px;text-align:center">
                               <p:dataGrid var="phone" value="#{phonesBean.phoneList}" columns="8"
                             rows="12" paginator="true"  
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
    rowsPerPageTemplate="9,12,15" style="text-align: center;">  
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Problem++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                                   <p:panel header="#{phone.model}" style="width: 175px"  >  
                                       <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">  
                                            <p:graphicImage value="#{phone.imageUrl}"/>
                                        </h:panelGrid>
                                       <p:commandButton value="click here" action="#{phonesBean.test()}"/>
                                    </p:panel>
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Problem+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                             </p:dataGrid>                                   
                            </th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>                                  
            </h:form>                
        </p:layoutUnit>  
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

I debbuged the code but test method wont call. and there is no any exception or error.

Comment: Try to look at this example/answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12857697/1692632](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12857697/1692632)
Maybe put phonesBean code here.

Comment: i tried but nothing happened

Comment: @smk Make sure that you are using `@ViewScoped` annotation with `@ManagedBean`.

Comment: Provide the source code for `phonesBean`.

Answer (score 0):

Write method name in EL without parenthesis and Add `ajax="false"`

```
<p:commandButton value="click here" action="#{phonesBean.test}" ajax="false"/>
```